# Can a nested random effect be examined as interaction?

Tags: r, anova, mixed-model

I have a dataset in R containing some experimental behavioral data with the following structure.

`SubjectID`: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5...

`Condition`: Condition 1, Condition 2, Condition 3, Condition 4 (each subject participated in all of the 4 conditions in the experiment)

`TimeStamp`: 1, 2, 3, 4 (in each of the condition, a measurement was obtained from each of the 4 time stamps. The time stamps were equally spaced and thus are treated as categorical variable)

`Measurement`: some kind of measurement which is a dependent variable

My research question is (1) whether there is a between-condition variation of the variation of measurement across time stamps (interaction between time stamp and condition), (2) whether the measurement differs across condition (main effect of condition).

My original thought was to fit an ANOVA model with both `Condition` and `TimeStamp` treated as a repeated-measures variables.

```
lme(Measurement ~ Condition * TimeStamp, random = ~ 1 | SubjectID, 
    data = dat)
```

However, it seems that `TimeStamp` is actually nested within the condition and violate the assumption of independence. Should I add a random effect of this nested relationship as follows?

```
lme(Measurement ~ Condition * TimeStamp, random = ~ 1 | SubjectID / Condition, 
    data = dat)
```

Can I define the `Condition:TimeStamp` as the interaction effect as well as specifying it as nested inside `SubjectID:Condition`?

Comment: Can you explain the experimental setup a bit better? Since you say `TimeStamp` is nested within `Condition` I'm thinking that all subjects were exposed to Condition 1 simultaneously, then to Condition 2 simultaneously, etc. Is that correct? If not, can you explain a bit more why you consider these two variables nested?

Comment: Hi Roland. The subjects were exposed to Condition 1 -> Condition 2 -> Condition 3 -> Condition 4 in a temporal order. However, the subjects did not participate in the experiment simultaneously (maybe in different days / weeks). The reason that I think time stamp is nested within condition is because time stamp 1 in condition 1 should be different than time stamp 1 in condition 2 due to the difference between conditions.

Comment: However, I also wonder whether time stamp 1 in condition 1 should be considered as same as time stamp 1 in condition 2 because they were measured at the same time (e.g. time stamp 1 was measured at the first 1 minute of the condition, no matter it was condition 1 or 2)

Comment: "time stamp 1 in condition 1 should be different than time stamp 1 in condition 2 due to the difference between conditions" Yes, and that is modeled by the fixed effects interaction.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. May I know if my understanding of nesting is incorrect?